# Java NIO: Avoid HashMapNode memory allocations?

Tags: java, nio

Classic NIO client:

```
Create a selector
Register channel to selector for READ WRITE
Loop: 
   select
   iterate selectedKeys
       do work for Readable channel and Writeable channel
```

I wrote a simple UDP NIO client for android like above, but found 30k+ HashMapNode memory allocations every 10 seconds. Since the channel was concerned both READ and WRITE, the select() call returned immediately because of it was writeable, during every select(), at least one SelectionKey was added to HashMap returned by SelectedKeys(). 
I changed the design to only register for READ at the beginning, and call select() with a small timeout(say 10ms), and if the buffer to write was not empty, register for WRITE, do the writes, and register for READ again, memory allocation problem fixed, but write operation will be delayed because you have to wait for the READ select timeout.

Any better approach?

Comment: Or should I add a selector.wakeup() call right after add something to write buffer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got it. Here it goes.

Main loop:

```
Open channel and configureBlocking(false)
Open selector
Register channel to selector, only concern about OP_READ
LOOP:
    selector.select() // No timeout
    if write buffer is empty or no channel been selected, continue
    LOOP for selectionKey in selectedKeys:
        if selectionKey is readable
             do read operation
        else if selectionKey is writeable
             do write operation
             register channel to OP_READ
        remove selectionKey from selectedKeys
```

Write:

```
write data to write buffer
register channel to OP_WRITE
selector.wakeup()
```